# Bootstrap doesn't works

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Lipsum</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Title"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></div>
            <br>
            <div class="Index">
                <i class="bi bi-app"></i> Lorem <!-- Başlık -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap doesn't works, how to fix it?

I don't want install any packages etc.

I tried few other icons and it again not worked, I don't have any idea for fix and I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: "While Bootstrap doesn’t include an icon set by default, we do have our own comprehensive icon library called Bootstrap Icons."

Comment: Have you tried including the [bootstrap icon library](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#install) that you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

first, put the bootstrap CDN and google fonts files below the title tag.
then put the js script file to last inside the body. then try again.

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Lipsum</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Title"><h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2></div>
            <br>
            <div class="Index">
                <i class="bi bi-app"></i> Lorem <!-- Başlık -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
```